# Convert a fasta file to Newick format

Tags: phylogenetics, fasta, phylogeny, format-conversion

My problem is (should be) pretty simple.

I have a series of 10 sequences which I wish to convert into a Newick format file - what would be good software to do this? I've tried using Jalview and am getting nowhere.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. Do you want to create a phylogenetic tree?

Answer (score 3):

The best would be Biopython using AlignIO, given they are all in a single file otherise SeqIO. The alignment approach,

```
from Bio import AlignIO
align = AlignIO.read("/home/path/myseq.fa", "fasta")
print(align)
with open("/home/path/example.nex", "w") as handle:
    SeqIO.write(align, handle, "nexus")
```

(not debugged)

[MEGAX](https://www.megasoftware.net/) or [ClustalX](http://www.clustal.org/clustal2/) which are nice GUI's that will also work. If you've not got Biopython installed then ClustalX is probably the easiest.

Comment: Thanks for your input - I'm a Python novice and don't have Biopython and looked at ClustalX - and then I found a solution using Clustalw which works quite nicely - see my answer - but I gave you a +1 for your contribution which led me to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@M__'s [answer](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/14944/9952) led me to [clustal.org](http://www.clustal.org/) and some searching led me to this page ([Christoph's](http://wiki.christophchamp.com/index.php?title=ClustalW)).

I tried compiling Clustalx (GUI - problem with qmake) which didn't work, but Clustalw (compiled to exe clustalw2) - the command line tool - worked a treat.

So, I had my `clustalw2` executable and my 25 *Drosophila* alcohol dehydrogenase protein sequences and I ran the following commands (from Christoph's page):

```
./clustalw2 -align -type=protein -infile=droso.fasta
```

This produces a droso.aln file which looks like this (only a few lines shown):

```
D_paulistorum               ETRVAEKLLEHPTQTTLACAQNFVKAIELNKNGAIWKLDLGTLEPIEWTK
D_insularis                 ETRVAEKLLEHPTQTTLACAQNFVKAIELNKNGAIWKLDLGTLEPIEWTK
D_equinoxialis              ETRVAEKLLEHPTQTTLACAQNFVKAIELNKNGAIWKLDLGTLEPIEWTK
D_willistoni                ETRVAEKLLEHPTQTTLACAQNFVKAIELNKNGAIWKLDLGTLEPIEWTK
                            *. *:**** ** *.:  *.:*********:*****:** .***.* *::
```

Then on Christoph's page, there is a section:

- Generate a Newick tree file

So, I followed the instructions and ran:

```
./clustalw2 -tree -infile=droso.aln
```

and obtained a file droso.ph which looks like a Newick format file to me (some lines):

```
(
(
(
D_madeirensis:0.00000,
D_subobscura:0.00787)
:0.00257,
D_guanche:0.00530)
:0.00336,
(
(
D_pseudoobscura:0.00000,
D_pseudoobscura_pseudo:0.00000)
:0.00262,
D_persimilis:0.00131)
:0.01239)
:0.01132,
D_ambigua:0.01821)
:0.00839,
```

So, it looks like I have a path to doing what I wanted in the first place - getting from .fasta to Newick format.

Then, using the programs [jalview](https://www.jalview.org/) and [figtree](http://tree.bio.ed.ac.uk/software/figtree/), I was able to draw trees and the like!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in Jalview.
In your alignment window, open the **Calculate** menu and select **Calculate Tree or PCA...**.
This will open a **Choose Calculation** window which you can use to select what kind of tree to build.
When you click on the **Calculate** button you will get another window with the tree in it.
In that window you can open the **File** menu and then select **Save as...** → **Newick Format**.  Hopefully this will do what you need.
[image: Combined 2-stage screenshot. Calculate->Calculate Tree or PCA...->Calculate->Save as...->Newick Format]